# Maven - special charecters in property name inside a pom

Tags: maven, properties, escaping, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I'm using the maven-properties-plugin to write my properties to file in order to be used by a third party application.

I would like to include a special character '$' in the property name.

For example:

```
<properties>
 <a$Boolean>SOMETHING</a$Boolean>
...
```

I failed to find an escape character.

I would appreciate a solution.

Thanks,
Ika.

Comment: Why do you need such a requirement. Why `aBoolean` or `a-Boolean` does not suffice?

Comment: Because the software using the output property file uses $ as delimiter in the variable name.

Answer (score 3):

`$` IS an an escape character for $.

Just put it twice, e.g.

```
<properties>
  <prop-with-dollar>Prop-with-$$</prop-with-dollar>
</properties>
```

the value of `prop-with-dollar` will be `Prop-with-$`

**EDIT**

After more careful reading, realized that the question is really about `$` in a property name.

It is not supported in Maven.  Which is not unreasonable. Many languages support only limited set of characters for variable names. For example, in Java `$!<>-` and many other characters cannot appear in a variable name.

Comment: I think the problem is with the property *name* not the value

Comment: Thanks you for answering. if this is the case I will do a workaround. there are a few and one of them is using the [replacer plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) to rename the output file.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was to use the [maven replacer plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin) by writing 'DOLAR' in every place I needed the dollar sign and then replacing all instances of 'DOLAR with '$'
Here is a code example:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Generating varfile for the install4j</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>write-active-profile-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputFile>C:\Dev\out.varfile</outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Replacing the DOLAR sign with real dollar sign in varfile</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <basedir>C:\Dev\</basedir>
          <file>out.varfile</file>
          <replacements>
            <replacement>
              <token>DOLAR</token>
              <value>\$$</value>
            </replacement>
          </replacements>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could work for you, it is worth trying this:

```
<project>
    <properties>
         <a\u0024Boolean>SOMETHING</a\u0024Boolean>
    </properties>
    <!--...-->
</project>
```

I add the same issue when I wanted to filter my **log4j.properties** file by resolving the key **'${log4j.dir}'** with the pom property value **'${user.home}'**.

Neither $${key} hack nor ${dollar}{key} hack worked for me.
I finally managed to do it using the HEXA notation for the $ char in the pom property.

```
<project>
    <properties>
    <log4j.dir>\u0024{user.home}</log4j.dir>
    </properties>
    <!--...-->
</project>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This method doesn't work